# Why is the toast message not shown?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows, win-universal-app, windows-store

In a windows 8.1 app, I am trying to make a toast notification using the code:

```
public class ToastController
{
    #region Public Methods and Operators

    /// <summary>
    /// The show.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">
    /// The message.
    /// </param>
    public void Show(string message)
    {
        // A single string wrapped across three lines of text.
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText01);

        toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text").First().InnerText = message;
        var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

        ToastNotifier notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        notifier.Show(toast);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

But I cannot see any toast messages at all when the `Show()` method is invoked. Am I missing anything?

---

Update: I have been able to get the toast message to show when debugging the windows app using `Local Machine`. However, the toast message is still not shown when launch in `Simulator`. Help please.

---

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I need to set up my app to enable toast notification:

```
<VisualElements 
    ...
    ToastCapable="true">
</VisualElements>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781238.aspx